# C - Dynamic Memory allocation - copy string

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy, realloc

for the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int size = 16, len = 0, c;
  char* data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(len == size) {
      size *= 2;
      char* data_new = (char*)realloc(data, sizeof(char) * size);
      if(data_new == NULL) {
        free(data);
        return -1;
      }
      if(data_new != data) {
        memcpy(data_new, data, size);
        data = data_new;
      }
    }
    data[len] = c;
    len++;
  }
  data[len] = '0';
  printf("%s\n", data);
  free(data);
  return 0;
}
```

I think the error lies in the realloc part because if im setting the size int high everything works fine.

Does someone have a tip for me how i can do this realloc thing correctly?

thx for your support

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The `memcpy` part is not needed as `realloc` is copying the data for you. `data` becomes (might become) invalid after `realloc`.

Comment: `data[len] = '0';` this is not a NUL terminator.

Comment: If your data is 16 or 32 or 64 characters long, `data[len]` will be one char after the valid memory after the main loop.

Comment: If your input is exactly 16 (or 32, or 64, ...) bytes you will try to write outside the allocated area.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy the data when `realloc` returns a different pointer - that is done for you. In fact it is a **mistake** because you are copying the data from a source that no longer exists, and twice the quantity that it had! So you only need

```
data = data_new;
```

Also this line is wrong

```
data[len] = '0';
```

it should be

```
data[len] = '\0';
```

and can also write beyond the memory bounds. You should be checking the size again before writing the terminator, or more simply, reallocate the memory when `size-1` has been used, because you know you'll be needing that extra byte.

```
if(len == size - 1) {
    // . . . 
}
```

Note too that if you are entering characters each separated by a newline then `getchar()` will read every newline too.